# How to do a real REST call when using gapi.client.myendpoint or gapi.client.request?

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to do a PUT call to a google enpoint that has 2 named params and a EntityObject that should then by in the body

```
@ApiMethod(name = "myMethod")
public MyEntity myMethod(@Named("param1") String param1, @Named("param2") String param2, MyEntity entity)
```

if i go to:

```
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?base=http://localhost:8889/_ah/api#p/myendpoint/v1/myendpoint.myMethod
```

I the 2 param fields that i need to but in and the request body i also get exactly the MyEntity fields that i can fill in.

it generates:

```
PUT http://localhost:8889/_ah/api/myendpoint/v1/mymethod/test1/test2
```

and the body has the fields that i filled in

And on the server side i exactly get what i am expecting to get.

But now i try to do it my self on the client side, but it always seem to generate a rpc call with everything in the body.

a call like this: (that "body" is a tryout)

```
gapi.client.myendpoint.mymethod({param1:"test1",param2:"test2",body:{field1:"data",field2:"data2"}})
```

i get a post request to this: (so it seems like a rpc call but thats not really what i want)

```
http://localhost:8889/_ah/api/rpc
```

and everything is just in the body..
And on my server side the EntityObject is just completely empty because it doesn't map correctly..

if i rebuild it my self using this:

```
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientrequest

    var request = gapi.client.request({
              path: "myendpoint/v1/mymethod/" + param1+ "/" +param2,
              method: 'PUT',
              body: {field1:"data",field2:"data2"}
            });
```

then i get a request to:

```
https://content.googleapis.com/myendpoint/v1/mymethod/test1/test2&alt=json
```

not sure where that "content.googlepis.com" is comming from (i am testing on localhost)
I thought if it is the host where the google api is coming from then it should be "apis.google.com"

if i use the same api on the same place directly to:

gapi.client.myendpoint.mymethod then it does go correctly just to localhost...

the only way that i seem to get it working (in a rpc way) is to merge the stuff:

```
var x = {field1:"data", field2:"data2"};
x.param1 = "test1";
x.param2 = "test2";
gapi.client.myendpoint.myMethod(x)
```

But this is quite a hack if you ask me because now i mix stuff, suddenly if i would add param1 to the EntityObject it gets also that 
(body and path (or even url params) stuff should be seperated.)

So it seems that the generate methods "gapi.client.xxxxendpoint" are always rpc calls
and the rest way of using is goes to the wrong host.

Answer (score 0):

according to the docs, you should be using "resource" instead of "body".

```
...    
method: 'PUT',
resource: {field1:"data",field2:"data2"}
...
```